# How can I convert a word flow chart (shown in photo) to latex?

Tags: tikz-trees, flow-charts, smartdiagram

[image]

I'm trying to use the "\usepackage{smartdiagram}" but I've some difficulties.
this is the code that I worte up to now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{%module shape=diamond,
%font=\scriptsize,     
set color list= {blue!30!cyan, blue!50!cyan,blue!50!cyan,blue!50!cyan},
module minimum width=2cm,
module minimum height=2cm,
module x sep=3cm,
module y sep=3cm,
text width=4cm,
%circular distance=2cm,
%circular final arrow disabled=true,
%border color= blue,
%text color= ,
back arrow disabled= true,
}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram]{PRODUCT TREE,
  ENTRY SYSTEM, LANDER, GNC }

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `smartdiagram` package is not the right tool for this kind of tree chart. Try with `forest`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges, for tree={edge=thick, rounded corners=6pt, blue!50!black,
fill=blue!10, draw, font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily}
[PRODUCT TREE
 [ENTRY SYSTEM
   [HEAT SHIELD]
   [LANDER,
      [GNC, for tree={folder, grow'=0,
           % parent anchor=-115, % to center folder root  
           anchor=west}, anchor=center, 
        [IMU ] 
       [CAMERA]
       [Whatever ...]
 ]]]]] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow great! Thank you very much! Can you help me to add just some little adjustments ? 1-Shadow around blocks, 2-All forks and branches of the same color (blue), 3-Is there a way to center automatically the vertical line below GNC block ?

Comment: For 1 and 2 add  `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}`  to the preamble and then   `for tree={edge=red, drop shadow, ...}`. For 3 simply uncomment the line 14.